# Can somebody explain the parts of this syntax, and how it would be used?

Tags: c#, syntax, parentheses

While going through some tutorials, I have encountered lines such as this:

```
((IDisposable)foo).Dispose();
```

Ignore the specific reference to Idisposable. I am curious as to why the parentheses are set the way they are and what they contain / do. I'm sure this is a very simple question to answer, but I have been unable to find the answer through searching, due to the generics of such a syntax. Help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You might be wondering why you need to cast before you call Dispose, since you probably already statically know `foo` is an `IDisposable`.  If `foo`'s, type implemented `IDisposable` explicitly, then you can't directly call `foo.Dispose()`, and you need to do this cast first.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx (@EugenRieck's answer answered the syntax, which was the main part, I figured this fit better as a comment)

Comment: To further extend @TimS's comment, the object is also not necessarily in the inheritance chain of what you are casting to/from as custom explicit or implicit cast operators can allow you to cast to/from completely unrelated types (though it has limitations, such as no interfaces allowed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first set of parentheses are casting it to an IDisposable object. For example

```
Object foo = new Object();
IDisposable ID;
```

Now `ID = foo` will give an error but `ID = (IDisposable)foo` will work.

The second set of parentheses allows you to access methods and properties of IDisposable objects, in this case the Dispose() method. If you type it out you will see that only once you have enclosed the second set of parentheses will intelisense show you the methods and properties of IDisposable objects.

Answer (score 2):

- Start with `foo`
- Prefix it with `(IDisposable)` to cast it to the requested interface
- Put this in brackets to tell .net that `foo` is the thing to be cast, not the result of `foo.Dispose()`
- Now add `.Dispose()` to address a method of the interface

Comment: +1 Keyword: [**cast**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Will it always be an interface inside the parentheses before foo?

Comment: No you can cast to any kind of object

Comment: @jaykreeler No, it need not be an interface (but it will often be). It can be anything, that `foo`can be casted to.

Comment: @EugenRieck And thanks to custom explicit / implicit cast operators, what `foo` can be cast to is not always visible in it's inheritance chain.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax:

```
var d = (IDisposable)foo;
```

Is called an Explicit Cast.

The syntax:

```
((IDisposable)foo).Dispose();
```

Explicitly casts `foo` into a temporary variable and calls `Dispose` on it (do note, a temporary variable ***is*** used here but you cannot see it, it is created by the compiler).

The brackets tell the compiler the order of precedence on the actions. In this case, it says to cast the variable to `IDisposable` before resolving the `Dispose` call. Because it is done before, the compiler now knows to resolve `Dispose` on a variable of type `IDisposable`.

You can see this behaviour in other forms:

```
(foo as IDisposable).Dispose();
```

Or:

```
string s = null;

while ((s = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
{
}
```

My first example casts using the `as` operator in the same manner as your own cast (in-line). My second example sets a variable `s` before proceeding to test it against `null`.

**My point being**, none of these would compile without the use of brackets to define the boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a shortcut when doing the conversion to IDisposable.

This...

```
((IDisposable)foo).Dispose();
```

is the same as this...

```
IDisposable i = (IDisposable)foo; 
i.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner set of parentheses around `IDisposable` turn it into a cast, and then the outer set of parentheses ensure that the cast occurs before the call to `Dispose()`.